# Run an LibreOffice Command-Line Script through a loop

Tags: loops, command-line, libreoffice

I have been able to successfully run the below code on an individual file, but I would like to find a way to have it run so that it loops through all the files shown in a directory. I believe that loops are possible within CMD.exe, but I am not having any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --convert-to DBF --infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2/33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2/68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2/72/2/73/2/74/2/75/2/76/2/77/2/78/2/79/2/80/2/81/2/82/2/83/2/84/2/85/2/86/2/87/2/88/2/89/2/90/2/91/2/92/2/93/2/94/2/95/2/96/2/97/2/98/2/99/2/100/2/101/2/102/2/103/2/104/2/105/2/106/2/107/2/108/2/109/2/110/2/111/2/112/2/113/2/114/2/115/2/116/2/117/2/118/2/119/2/120/2/121/2/122/2/123/2/124/2/125/2/126/2/127/2/128/2/129/2/130/2/131/2/132/2/133/2/134/2/135/2/136/2,0,false,false" C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\57826001_JQSAMPLE.csv --outdir C:\Users\jdavidson\desktop\complete
```

If you have any ideas for how I might be able to achieve this it be a huge help. I am working to build this as part of a larger workflow and make it repeatable.

***UPDATE***

I was able to iterate(Loop) through all of the files in my directory by creating a batch file and placing it within the directory that I am going to be using for converting moving forward

```
for /r %%i in (*.csv) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --convert-to DBF --infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2/33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2/68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2/72/2/73/2/74/2/75/2/76/2/77/2/78/2/79/2/80/2/81/2/82/2/83/2/84/2/85/2/86/2/87/2/88/2/89/2/90/2/91/2/92/2/93/2/94/2/95/2/96/2/97/2/98/2/99/2/100/2/101/2/102/2/103/2/104/2/105/2/106/2/107/2/108/2/109/2/110/2/111/2/112/2/113/2/114/2/115/2/116/2/117/2/118/2/119/2/120/2/121/2/122/2/123/2/124/2/125/2/126/2/127/2/128/2/129/2/130/2/131/2/132/2/133/2/134/2/135/2/136/2,0,false,false" C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\57826001_JQSAMPLE.csv --outdir C:\Users\jdavidson\desktop\complete %%i
```

Note that I used a for Loop to achieve what I wanted.

```
for /r %%i in ('list directory if command not being run in specific directory already; you can also but * for all files in directory or *.ext for the extension of only certain files) do 'add in command %%i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: You can actually convert multiple documents with just one execution of Open/Libre Office.. without a loop.  Just use a wildcard, eg:

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --convert-to DBF mydir\*.csv
```

Option 2: I assume that Windows has a limit on the number of files you can pass in that way.. not sure what that limit is.. but if you exceed that limit, you can use this python program I wrote to do this just a few days ago.. as part of a project I am still working on.  In my case I am converting `.doc` to `.odt`, and obviously my directories aren't the same as yours.  But it would be quite easy for you to adjust this to your needs...  One thing I wanted to do with mine is to check for the existence of the converted file and skip it if it exists.. so that if a few new files are added it can be run again to convert them without redoing them all...

The `docpath` should be set to the location of your files, and `soffice` to the pathname of your Calc exe.. and if you leave things the way I have them, that's where the program puts the converted files too.. and checks for their existence.  Also, I walk the path looking for input files.. so if for whatever reason you have your files in different subdirectories, it will find them and put the conversion in the same directory.

```
import os, sys, re, subprocess

docpath = 'doc'
soffice = 'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe'

convert = '"%s" --headless --convert-to odt --outdir "%s" "%s"'

def plog(fmt = '', *args):
    sys.stdout.write(fmt % args)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def log(fmt = '', *args):
    plog((fmt + '\n'), *args)

def convert():
    odtfiles = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(docpath):
        for file in files:
            if not file.endswith('.doc'):
                continue
            docfile = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            odtfile = re.sub(r"\.doc$", ".odt", docfile)
            plog("%s -> %s: " % (docfile, odtfile))
            if not os.path.isfile(odtfile):
                 plog('Converting.. ')
                 subprocess.check_output(convert % (soffice, docpath, docfile), shell=True)
            log('OK.')
            odtfiles.append(odtfile)
        return odtfiles

odtfiles = convert()
```

Just install Python27.. and set the `convert` string to have the correct settings for your conversion.  Along with a few other changes that should be pretty easy.. but if you need help, ask in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am not familiar with Python, but have been reading up on it. Any help you could provide me to get your code to work would be greatly appreciated. I had tried the wildcard *.csv prior to posting originally, and it didn't yield any results.

Comment: little_birdie - You are correct that you should be able to use a wildcard, but when using the DBF with a filter you cannot use the wildcard feature. I did find that the following would work: `code` for %%x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9) do echo V%%x.txt `code` I manipulated the for statement to run through all the files listed. see my update above